# I am using pandas profiling in google coolab and found some errors

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

the problem statement is

ImportError: cannot import name 'Buffer' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)

i already had the pandas profiling installed. but then again i again run the command

pip install Pandas_Profiling

and then to find out the output

import  pandas_profiling
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(hotel_data)

i have already imported pandas

Comment: this issue has been reported here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/4065 
Would recommend to use `ydata-profiling` instead, `pandas_profiling` has been deprecated - https://pypi.org/project/ydata-profiling/

Answer (score 0):

Try to do **!pip install ydata_profiling** and go to runtime > restart session